# GROUP BY on a name field, choose row with the lowest ID

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am doing a similar search:

```
select id, company_name from cars where company_name='Audi';
```

The output is:

```
+--------+----------------------+
| id     | company_name         |
+--------+----------------------+
| 349115 | Audi                 |
| 349117 | Audi                 |
| 349118 | Audi                 |
| 349119 | Audi                 |
| 349120 | Audi                 |
| 349121 | Audi                 |
| 349122 | Audi                 |
| 349123 | Audi                 |
```

Because I want to see every car company only once, I do:

```
select id, company_name from cars where company_name='Audi' group by company_name;
```

And the output:

```
+--------+----------------------+
| id     | company_name         |
+--------+----------------------+
| 349115 | Audi                 |
```

I've got returned only one record, and with the lowest ID from the table for this record. That's what I wanted. I've been testing this and if there were multiple records (found cars) for a search, `group by` returned always the record with the lowest ID (the one that was entered to the database as the first one).

Is this a rule `group by` or is it just a coincidence? Does `group by` return always the record with the lowest ID, so I can rely on that?

Comment: is id is primary key?

Comment: No, don't rely on this. The query would be a syntax error in most other RDBMS besides MySQL - if you want the lowest one, use `MIN(id)`

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` is not guaranteed to return the first row; it returns values from an *indeterminate* row or rows.  You should not use this construct, something that is only allowed in MySQL.

Use `join` and `group by`:

```
select c.*
from cars c join
     (select company_name, min(id) as minid
      from cars
      group by company_name
     ) cc
     on c.id = cc.minid;
```

If you have one company and want one row:

```
select c.*
from cars c
where company_name = 'Audi'
order by id
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not rely on this, but you can use aggregation function , on the columns that are not part of the group by clause, so you can put min(id)